# Calculating the center of a turning circle

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the midpoint of a turning circle. In the attached picture, my unit is at location U. I want to compute the trajectory of the unit as it turns toward the starred location.

I understand that to achieve this I need to know the location of point P, whose coordinates are (a,b). I also understand that I can do this using some simple trig:

```
a = x - cos(theta) * r
b = y - sin(theta) * r
```

My problem is that I do not know the value of the angle Theta which sits between the sides of the right-triangle named "R" and "X-A". All I know is:

1. The radius of the turning circle.
2. The orientation of the unit.

How can I solve this problem and others like it more generally?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Question details keep on changing, so I'll post 3 different answers covering all of them*

**So you know the radius R and unit location U and facing direction F.**

- normalize the unit direction F
- make a perpendicular to F (you need to pick from 2 directions, pick one that is closer to units target), we call it F2
- multiply perpendicular F2 with radius R, (call it F2R)
- take location of the unit U and add multiplied perpendicular F2R to it
- that's your circle midpoint P.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Question details keep on changing, so I'll post 3 different answers covering all of them*

**If we know unit location U, circle radius R and target location S**

Here's a generic approach to the case. Let's try to parametrize it now.

- Find a point in between Star and U - that is our MidPoint.
- Make a perpendicular from that point (you might want to have it facing against unit movement vector).
- Now, that MidPoint + Offset in the direction is the center of your circle.
  (*Note that Radius cannot be smaller than half the distance between Star and U.*)
- Now we need to find an Offset that will make the circle Radius that you need. As you see we have a right triangle between circle center (P), Star (S) and MidPoint (M).
- From the math class: `MS^2 + MP^2 = PS^2`.
- `MP = Sqrt(PS^2 - MS^2)`
- Knowing MP length it's a matter of math to find coordinates (a,b) of P

[image]

Comment: Hi Krom,

The position of the starred location is initially unknown. I guess I should have omitted it entirely from the diagram. The unit will decide, at some stage, to stop turning and move toward its target. The target can be anywhere; not necessarily on the perimeter of the circle.

Comment: Without knowing Star location, you have just a U and Radius. These 2 are not enough to make a circle.

Comment: The radius "r" defines the circle. I want to know its midpoint so I can visualise the path my agent will take when turning.

Comment: Once again, if you have only U and Radius, there is infinity of circles of that radius around U. Take a piece of paper, place a point U, now draw multitude of lines from U with length R into all directions. End of each line is a center of circle with radius R and point U on it.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding here. As far as I can see there are only two **turning** circles, depending on whether the unit is turning left or right. In the example I give, the unit is turning left, toward the starred location.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the critical piece and you also know Unit facing direction?

Comment: Sure, yes. I always know the direction the unit is facing. How does that help?

Comment: Please see my other answer.

Comment: OK, I've updated the question to clarify this ambiguity. We seem to now be back at square 1. Is it possible to use the orientation of the unit to somehow compute the location of point P?

Comment: We are at square 3 ;) Star is off the table and we know there's facing direction. Please see my third answer.

Comment: Nice work! I was beating my head trying to come up with an approach using the trigonometric functions. It did not occur to me to just compute a perpendicular vector. Thank you, Krom!

Answer (score 0):

*Question details keep on changing, so I'll post 3 different answers covering all of them*

**If you know only unit location U and turning circle radius R**

This can not be done distinctively if the only things you know are the location U and circle radius R.

Take a look at illustration below:

[image]

There is infinity of circles with radius R around the unit location U. You need a rule of picking only one of those turning circles (e.g. unit facing direction will eliminate all but 2 circles and you drop one that is farther from target location).